# How to control horizontal markers in Windows DataVisualization Error Bar Chart

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-visualization

I have an error bar chart (SeriesChartType.ErrorBar) created using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting. The default marker width on the error bars is too small, but I don't know how to change it. Changing Series.MarkerSize had no effect, unless I change the marker type to something other than None.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the width of the error bar you need to set the `PointWidth` or `PixelPointWidth` custom properties of the `ErrorBar` series:

In code:

```
series2.CustomProperties = "PixelPointWidth=20";
```

In VS designer:

1. Go to "Chart Properties" and open the series collection editor
2. Select series and scroll down to the "Custom Properties"
3. Expand "Custom Properties" and set the `PointWidth` to 1 – that would make it as wide as a dynamic width of datapoint (based on how close the datapoints are)
4. If you want to set pixel width - set the `PixelPointWidth` custom property